# Change TOC Numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

How can I change the numbering of just one section on TOC?

**Example:**

*(Actual situation)*

A Introduction to Dynamics ......................... #

*(Desired situation)*

Appendix A Introduction to Dynamics ......... #

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{6,0,111}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,125,0}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.png}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centering SUMÁRIO}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

\titlecontents{section}[0em]{\medskip\bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[0em]{\smallskip}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[0em]{\smallskip\bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{paragraph}[0em]{\smallskip}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subparagraph}[0em]{\smallskip\itshape}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing

\usepackage{units}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0mm}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{5mm}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0mm}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0mm}
    \setlength{\mathindent}{12.5mm}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{txfonts}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\footnotesize\thepage}%
\makeatother

\usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries\uppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\uppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[hang]{\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \newpage
    \appendix
    \titlelabel{APPENDIX \thetitle\ -- }

    \section{Sec 1}

    \newpage
    \titlelabel{APPENDIX \thetitle\ -- }

    \section{Sec 2}

    \newpage
    \titlelabel{APPENDIX \thetitle\ -- }

    \section{Sec 3}     

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example can you add the following code after the command `\appendix`:

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Appendix~\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection~\arabic{subsection}}
    \titlelabel{APPENDIX \thetitle\ -- }
```

With `\Alph{section}` you get capital letters instead of numbers and the first `\renewcommand` just adds `Appendix~` to the section header (if you need it in capital letters write `APPENDIX` instead of my `Appendix`). You need to comment your `\titlelabel` commands.  See my changes marked with `% <=====` in the following MWE.

Complete code (I commented your `\newpage` to have TOC and appendix on one page):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{6,0,111}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,125,0}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.png}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centering SUMÁRIO}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

\titlecontents{section}[0em]{\medskip\bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[0em]{\smallskip}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[0em]{\smallskip\bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{paragraph}[0em]{\smallskip}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subparagraph}[0em]{\smallskip\itshape}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing

\usepackage{units}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0mm}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{5mm}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0mm}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0mm}
    \setlength{\mathindent}{12.5mm}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{txfonts}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\footnotesize\thepage}%
\makeatother

\usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries\uppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\uppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[hang]{\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%\newpage
\appendix
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Appendix~\Alph{section}}% <==========================
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection~\arabic{subsection}}
    %\titlelabel{APPENDIX \thetitle\ -- }% <==========================

    \section{Sec 1}

    %\newpage
    %\titlelabel{APPENDIX \thetitle\ -- }% <==========================

    \section{Sec 2}

    %\newpage
    %\titlelabel{APPENDIX \thetitle\ -- }% <==========================

    \section{Sec 3}     

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of mwe]

Comment: @PedroFelipeOliveira you are welcome!